# Antisemitism on politics.se

Tags: discussion, moderation, code-of-conduct, antisemitism

I didn't want to have to post this, but here we are.

Yesterday I flagged a comment by a user on one of their own answers to a question on the main site, that repeated the baseless conspiracy theory that the October 7th attack by Hamas was a deliberate false flag engendered by Israel. Today the comment is gone but the user remains unsuspended, the latter which is... surprising and frankly, rather disappointing to me.

While it is not my place to tell the moderators how to run things, using this site as a vehicle to propagate a conspiracy theory regarding a verified terrorist attack - that resulted in hundreds of deaths and dozens of hostages, some of whom remain captives - seems like an obvious and blatant violation of the Code of Conduct.

Comment: That particular conspiracy theory has actual evidence both for and against it. It's not the same level of insanity as, say, the idea that humans have never been to the moon. Not everyone knows everything during an active war.

Comment: What it seems to me is that you object to the content of said comment, and are effectively attempting to have that content censored by using the CoC as a hammer to do so. Instead of attempting to shut down content that you believe to be baseless conspiracy theories, you'd be better served considering how these theories came to be, and why they are held by many people.

Comment: My previous comment is an alteration of something *you've said* here on Politics Meta. You've written multiple answers on Meta ([example](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6288/a/6296#6296), [example](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4624/a/4637#4637)) explaining why you feel that content which someone believes to be untrue should not be censored just because someone believes it to be untrue. Now that *you* believe something to be untrue, you are asking why it wasn't censored since you believe it clearly deserves to be censored.

Comment: To quote from your answer(s) some more **"no accredited and impartial body has made formal findings of guilt by said forces"** and **"apparent evidence of wrongdoing is not necessarily proof of wrongdoing"**. UN refused to condemn Hamas. At best the ICJ said they took hostages. I doubt the comment you refer to denied that Hamas took hostages. So, yeah, devil's advocate is a thing that can bite you back. You don't seem to believe that Western media is neutral enough when it comes to Russia/Ukraine. Why do you believe it so when it comes to Hamas/Israel?

Comment: This post seems like an obvious and blatant attempt to get a user whose views you disagree with suspended.

Answer (score 10):

My understanding, based on my own experience as a moderator on another SE site, is that a single comment is simply not enough to warrant a suspension, regardless of what the comment may have said. At most, it warrants a polite but firm message in the user's inbox reminding them of the Code of Conduct - which, for all we know, the moderator in this case did in fact do.

If the user in question demonstrates a *consistent pattern* of CoC violations, and/or refuses to stop after being warned, that's when a suspension is justified. But from what you've mentioned in the question - a single comment promoting a controversial (though, as noted in the comments, not *entirely* baseless) theory - there simply isn't enough here to justify a suspension.

On the other side of the coin, if you want to accuse the moderators of not doing enough to combat anti-semitism on the site, you'll want to provide more (and better) examples than just the one.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, there is a group of users here supportive of Hamas, who downvote any question that appears either critical to Hamas or somewhat positive about Israel. Some time ago I proposed tagging questions dealing with Hamas, reminding that it is recognized as a terrorist organization by the US,  the UK, the EU, and many other countries... for some reason I cannot find this question anymore - likely it was deleted. At the time the main objection was that some of the users come from the countries that do not proscribe Hamas, and they are entitle to their opinion. While it appears as a plausible argument to me, it is worth noting that (for good or for bad) the moderators seem to be more decisive in dealing with anything that they perceive as pro-Russian or critical of the western policies in Ukraine.

Comment: Funny that this post has about as many upvotes (and DVs) as your extremely strong, sometimes extremely long, and often barely on-topic anti-Hamas posts typically get here. It's not that I like Hamas, but you seem to turn every remotely related Q here in a MEMRI-style posting. And there's clearly also a group of users here who loves and enables this kind of posts/behavior.

Comment: @Dolphin613Motorboat *you seem to turn every remotely related Q here in a MEMRI-style posting* - I'll take it as a compliment. I do think that a good answer should not only report the facts, but also explain them.

Answer (score 1):

To be fair, while there is a fair bit of anti-Israel drivel and hate being pasted around, so is anti-Palestine stuff (to be clear, I am A-OK with anti-Hamas).

It is to be expected, in a situation of such vested hostilities in the real world, that some of that hostility will arrive here as well.  We've certainly seen that in the past with Pakistan vs India affiliated posters.  Ditto Ukraine vs Russia.

Flag it, let the moderators delete and suspend, as per policy.  But just because you don't like something doesn't make it suspend-worthy, in isolation.

As far as the several questions we've had questioning whether 10/7 was terroristic in nature, a false flag, or targeted civilians?  Well, they've generally turned out to have the opposite effect to what their OP intended as they get massive downvotes and highly upvoted counter-argument answers, which shoot down the original claims.

Those questions aren't really doing the Palestinian cause any favor.

p.s. And, as far as I can tell, one side's rabid supporters tend to end up more in the suspension doghouse than the other's rabid supporters.  Possibly because one side is marginally more careful/measured in what they say.